# How to insert value in column if condition is true using Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset and I am trying to create a condition, where if the value in the Percentage cell is positive, I want the match cell to show the subsequent Percentage value eg (i+1). However, I wanted to ask how would I be able to perform this operation without using a loop. For example, in row 0 and Match, it would display the value -0.34.

```
        User Percent      Match 
0          A    0.87        NaN   
1          A   -0.34        NaN    
2          A    0.71        NaN    
3          A   -0.58        NaN    
4          B   -1.67        NaN  
5          B   -0.44        NaN  
6          B   -0.72        NaN  
7          C    0.19        NaN  
8          C    0.39        NaN  
9          C   -0.28        NaN  
10         C    0.53        NaN
```

Additionally, how would I be able to have a summation of the subsequent two value proceeding a positive number in the Percent cell. I have the following code, but I am making an error in indexing the row location.

```
df1.ix[df1.Percent >=0, ['Match']] = df1.iloc[:1]['Match']; df1
```

Comment: It should be 1 problem per question really

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it might be an extension of the probelm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first part you can use `loc` with a boolean condition and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
In [5]:
df.loc[df['Percent']>0,'Match'] = df['Percent'].shift(-1)
df

Out[5]:
   User  Percent  Match
0     A     0.87  -0.34
1     A    -0.34    NaN
2     A     0.71  -0.58
3     A    -0.58    NaN
4     B    -1.67    NaN
5     B    -0.44    NaN
6     B    -0.72    NaN
7     C     0.19   0.39
8     C     0.39  -0.28
9     C    -0.28    NaN
10    C     0.53    NaN
```

For the summation you can do the following:

```
In [15]:
def func(x):
    return df['Percent'].iloc[x.name-2:x.name].sum()
df['sum'] = df[df['Percent']>0][['Percent']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
df

Out[15]:
   User  Percent  Match   sum
0     A     0.87  -0.34  0.00
1     A    -0.34    NaN   NaN
2     A     0.71  -0.58  0.53
3     A    -0.58    NaN   NaN
4     B    -1.67    NaN   NaN
5     B    -0.44    NaN   NaN
6     B    -0.72    NaN   NaN
7     C     0.19   0.39 -1.16
8     C     0.39  -0.28 -0.53
9     C    -0.28    NaN   NaN
10    C     0.53    NaN  0.11
```

This uses a slight trick to mask the df and return the col of interest but force to a df (by using double square brackets `[[]]`) so we can call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and use `axis=1` to iterate row-wise. This allows us to access the row index via the `.name` attribute. We can then use this to slice the df and return the `sum`.

Comment: Thank you for providing solutions for both problems!!